# Python: Simple for loop syntax error

Tags: ubuntu, python, for-loop, syntax

I want to parse a website containing the current price of tesla stock, and send it to an arduino, to display it to it's lcd. Does anyone have any idea why does the syntax error occurs, while the syntax is good? I use an ubuntu server, installed with the latest: urllib, python, and regex

```
#!/bin/python3
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

url = 'https://money.cnn.com/quote/quote.html?symb=TSLA'
values = {'s':'basics', 'submit':'search'}

data=urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data=data.encode('utf-8')
req=urllib.request.Request(url, data)
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

#print(respData)
pg = re.findall(r'treamFormat="ToHundredth"streamFeed="BatsUS">(.*?)</span><div class="wsod_quoteLabel">', str(respData)
for eachP in pg:
print(eachP)
```

**The error**

```
  File "./htmlto2.py", line 17
    for eachP in pg:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're missing indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing `)` on the previous line for the `re.findall(` bit. Also, as roaima pointed out, your `print(eachP)` is not indented.